# How to avoid N+1 in Pundit policy for show?/update?/destroy?

Tags: activeadmin, pundit, rolify

I'm using ActiveAdmin gem together with Pundit (and Rolify) gem.

This is how I wrote my policy (taken from: https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/master/spec/support/templates/policies/application_policy.rb):

```rb
class ApplicationPolicy
  attr_reader :user, :record

  def initialize(user, record)
    @user = user
    @record = record
  end

  def show?
    scope.where(id: record.id).exists?
  end

  def create?
    user.has_role?(:staff, record.company)
  end

  def update?
    scope.where(id: record.id).exists?
  end

  def destroy?
    scope.where(id: record.id).exists?
  end

  def destroy_all?
    true
  end

  def scope
    Pundit.policy_scope!(user, record.class)
  end

  class Scope
    attr_reader :user, :scope

    def initialize(user, scope)
      @user = user
      @scope = scope
    end

    def resolve
      if user.admin?
        scope.all
      else
        company_ids = Company.with_role(:staff, user).map(&:id)
        scope.where(company_id: company_ids)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This causes N+1 query each time `scope.where(id: record.id).exists?`. On index page, `show?`, `update?` and `destroy?` are called for each record in the table.

How can I avoid the N+1 query in this case?

I'm trying to:
1) Include/preload roles together with user for calls to `current_user`
2) I'm trying to memoize the `scope` or use some array method to prevent hitting the db with `where` and `exists?` methods. But `scope.find` still makes the db query for every new row.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

first of all, I suggest adding a method to the `User` object to return company_ids where it is staff helps.

```rb
class User #or AdminUser right?
  def company_ids
      @company_ids ||= Company.with_role(:staff, self).map(&:id)
  end
end
```

than you can change

```rb
 def destroy?
    scope.where(id: record.id).exists?
  end
```

to

```rb
 def destroy?
    return true user.admin?
    user.company_ids.include?(record.company_id)
  end
```

and resolve method for Scope now looks this way

```rb
def resolve
      if user.admin?
        scope.all
      else
        scope.where(company_id: user.company_ids)
      end
    end
  end
```